# Elasticsearch symbol synonym for non English keyboardss

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am indexing a website with `Elasticsearch` that has many names that have Scandinavian characters. The problem is that our users generally use an American English keyboard and replace these characters with their closest English letter. For example, what is indexed is `Tromsø` but what is searched for is `Tromso`.

How can I add character synonyms so that both the original characters and the English characters would be equal when searching in `Elasticsearch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom analyzer and set `char filter` for it like this

```
PUT my_index
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "char_filter": [
                        "my_char_filter"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "char_filter": {
                "my_char_filter": {
                    "type": "mapping",
                    "mappings": [
                        "ø => o",
                        "á => a"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": [
                "lowercase"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

In this case both `Tromsø` and `Tromso` will give the same output term. Take a look at this topic about creating your custom analyzer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html

Comment: While this does work, it makes the searches case sensitive. When I search for Tromsø / Tromso its all fine, but if I search for tromsø / tromso then I get 0 results. How can I keep it case insensitive while still mapping the characters?

Comment: In this case you should add `lowercase` token filter to your analyzer. See updated answer.